# How to make cleverref start appendix with number instead of a letter?

Tags: cleveref, appendix

I'm using `cleverref`, but I want the appendices to be numbered as `Appendix 1`, `Appendix 1.2`, and so on. Instead, it starts with letters as `Appendix A`, `Appendix A.1`, etc.
I have the following lines currently:

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
```

Any ideas how to make change to appendix numbering?

Comment: The numbering style of sections in the appendix portion of the full document is, in general, set by the document class. `cleveref` simply inherits those settings. Thus, please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico I updated my question.

Comment: You can't use `\section` after `\appendix` with that document setup: I get `** WARNING: Ignoring useless \section in Appendix`. Please, add minimal code to show how you get “Appendix 1” and so on.

Comment: @egreg You can ignore the section part I removed. The problem is I get `Appendix A` and so on, but instead I want to get `Appendix 1`. So I want to replace letters with numbers.

Comment: @egreg - Unfortunately, the OP has failed to provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Indeed, `\section` commands don't work after `\appendix` under `\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}`, the `\subsection` and `\subsection` commands do still work. They are numbered `1` and `1.1`, resp., but `\cref` produces `A` and `A.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an incomplete answer.

Generally you can use `\renewcommand` after `\appendix` to change appendix counter to arabic numbers. But for some reason `cref` doesn't inherit this change and shows alphabet count. Code and image below.

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
  \section{Some section}
  \section{A section}
  \appendix
  % after appendix renew command for \thesection
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
  % also in IEEEtran it seems appendices start at subsection level
  \subsection{Some appendix}\label{appendix-label}
  \cref{appendix-label}
  \subsection{section in appendix again}\label{appendix-label2}
  \cref{appendix-label2}
\end{document}
```

[image]